# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass rails with slug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

when I attempt to run my code, I got the error above.
I try to transform the url products with FriendlyId gem . It works but when I try to see my product, I got this error :

```
NoMethodError in Products#show
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Request
Parameters:
{"name"=>"tablette-chocolat-guanaja"}
```

Here's my models/product.rb :

```
has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
before_save :update_slug

def update_slug
    self.slug = name.parameterize
end

def to_param
    slug
end
```

my products_controller.rb :

```
before_action :set_product, only:[:show]

def show
    @order_item = current_order.order_items.new
end

private

def set_product
    @product = Product.find_by_slug(params[:id])
end
```

my view/show.html.erb :

```
<%= render "product_show", product: @product, order_item: @order_item %>
```

and _product_show.html.erb :

```
<p ><%= product.name %></p>
<%= form_for order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.number_field :quantity, value: order_item.quantity.to_i, class: "form-control", min: 1, max: 99 %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>
  <p><%= currency_euro product.price %></p></br>
  <p><%= image_tag product.image %></p>
  <p><%= image_tag product.image_pres1 %></p>
  # etc.
```

Any idea ?

EDIT

Here's the full error message :

```
Started GET "/products/tablette-chocolat-guanaja" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-20 16:52:06 +0100
Processing by ProductsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"name"=>"tablette-chocolat-guanaja"}
Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`active` = 1 AND `products`.`slug` IS NULL LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product_show.html.erb (1.8ms)
Rendered products/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

EDIT2

My fault, I added "resources :products, param: :name" in product's routes, sorry...

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Answer (score 0):

first you don't need to update manually slug, gem will do it for you just execute this code

```
Product.all.each(&:save)
```

also this

```
def set_product
    @product = Product.find_by_slug(params[:id])
end
```

you can replace

```
def set_product
    @product = Product.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, now I got this error : "Couldn't find Product without an ID" in set_product method

Comment: first of all you need to re-save all of your products it will automatically fill slug field. Check plz do you retrieve object with empty slug field

Comment: The slug is present in my products : ", slug: "tablette-chocolat-guanaja"" the problem is that the only parameter that is passed is the name

Answer (score 0):

probably because the creation of this product was before install friendly_id. Did you try this?: `Profile.find_each(&:save)` to rails console to save slugs to your old products?

Comment: Did you put slug to the product_params method in product_controller?

Comment: Yes I did it and in model with attr_accessible